# Use Unicode In A UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, uilabel

I have a `UILabel`, and I want a unicode character to be in it.  I've seen this sample code in another app and it works perfectly; however, in my app, I get a blank square.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
[self.button setTitle:@"\uf05a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the Chinese character contained in that Unicode escape is *not* a valid Unicode character.  This means that while it may exist in the Unicode spec, it has yet to be implemented, or standardized, so UILabel cannot render it.  Talk to a font designer and see about getting that glyph in a custom font package, or use a different one.